# 'Other Volumes' storage increases after deleting secondary volumes

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, apfs, disk-volume

Long story short: ive noticed each time i create a secondary volume and removed it after some testing, the storage labeled 'Other Volumes' in the Disk Utility app has increased each time by half a gigabyte. I know for a fact that adding the new volume and removing it after the testing is what causes the 'Other Volumes' storage to increase by half a gigabyte each time, i just dont really understand why since im deleting the volume with all it's contents.

Originally the 'Other Volumes' was at 1.75GB before i did the first secondary volume, after removing the second volume it went up to 2.28GB; i just finished another test on another secondary volume and it went up again to 2.82GB for storage. I have a feeling that creating the new volumes and removing is what's causing the 'Other Volumes' to increase by half a gigabyte each time, but i want to know if there is some way to reduce it back down, preferably back to the 1.75 GB.

Is there a way to reduce the storage space of 'Other Volumes' without having to do something extreme?

Comment: Were these volumes used for installing a separate OS by any chance?

Comment: @ user3052786 yes, i had to re-install the current MacOS system(High Sierra 10.13.6) on both secondary volumes

Comment: what do you see when you run `diskutil apfs list`?

Comment: @user3052786 here's what i see when i ran that in the Terminal app
https://imgur.com/a/9QEejNq

Comment: Creating two or more bootable volumes in the same container uses the same "Recovery" volume.  Every user gets a UUID specific folder on Recovery (and Preboot for that matter), including  a close to 500 MB BaseSystem.dmg.  Those do not get deleted with the 2ⁿᵈ volume, but persist.

Comment: Sorry, not user, but volume (file system UUID).

Comment: @Redarm can the UUID specific folder get deleted within time, since the volume is gone will the folder be deleted after the system realizes theres no second volume?

Comment: @no nope Not that I have noticed.  Mine's been there for weeks now and has grown to 4 GB with 8 entries for various UUID folders (even updates seem to change the file system UUID and create more folders, judging by the SystemVersion.plist files in each folder).

Comment: @Redarm is there a way to remove the secondary UUID folders from recovery? kinda dumb imo that it stays after the volume is deleted/removed

Comment: @no nope; You should be able to delete them by mounting the Recovery volume (`diskutil mount diskXsX` - find your disk number and slice via `diskutil list`, e.g. disk1s3 for my Recovery volume) under `/Volumes` and just deleting the folders with an older UUID and SystemVersion in Finder.  Make sure you don't delete the current ones.  You can find the "File System UUID" in Disk Utility's Info pane for each volume in the container).

Comment: @Redarm would you mind going step-by-step of how to do it(i.e 1:open ___ 2:paste ___ 3:etc.) as im not very confident in doing Terminal commands as I don't want to screw something up and also I won't know how to unmount the Recovery Volume afterwards if I do succeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrades and deletions with subsequent recreation of volumes in a multi-volume container leave the container untouched and new (more) "file system UUID" specific folders are created for each volume in the shared "Recovery" volume.  Those folders each include a close to 500 MB BaseSystem.dmg

These older folders are not cleared by the system.

To remove the older unused folders, make sure you are booted into a volume outside the container with the Recovery in question.
1.) Then first run the following command in Terminal (to be found in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app, or search for it via Spotlight)

`diskutil list`

...and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. This will show your disk identifier for "Recovery" in the output, which in your case is `disk1s3`

2.) Now mount the "Recovery" volume with this command:

`diskutil mount disk1s3`

...and press <kbd>enter</kbd>again, which will mount "Recovery" in `/Volumes/Recovery` (press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to make the invisible directory visible in Finder, if necessary).

Navigate to it and you can inspect the various folders for their content (e.g. the SystemVersion.plist).  You can also delete them (I'd like to add that I do not suggest this though.  Instead some feedback to Apple to clean up those older folders is what I did).

Since you want to keep the currently in use ones, you will have to find your volumes' current "file system UUID".

I'm using "Disk Utility.app" for that (/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app):
Select **all** your current volumes (one by one) and with one selected press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> to bring up the Info panel.  There look for "file system UUID" in the left column and note its value.

Do that for all other volumes.
If you've left the Finder window with the mounted Recovery open, you should now notice the ones you've found in Disk Utility also appear as folder names in the "Recovery" volume.  Leave those alone.

Only delete the ones that currently don't correspond to an existing volume, as shown in Disk Utility and empty the Trash, if you use Finder.

The mounted "Recovery" will get unmounted the next time you restart, or you can just right-click the volume icon in Finder and eject it.

---

### **If you don't have a volume outside the container to boot into**

You can also delete those folders from "Recovery" itself.
Boot into the "Recovery" volume by holding <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
Launch "Terminal" from the "Utilities" menu.

Now follow the instructions, as above, running the two commands mentioned.
1.) The first one...
`diskutil list` 
...to find your Recovery's disk identifier (which should be different from the one found, when not booted into Recovery above).
It (the container in question) will look similar to this:

```
/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +62.5 GB    disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s2
   1:                APFS Volume Installation1           23.8 GB    disk5s1
   2:                APFS Volume Installation2           12.2 GB    disk5s2
   3:                APFS Volume Preboot                 136.9 MB   disk5s3
   4:                APFS Volume Recovery                3.1 GB     disk5s4
   5:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk5s5
```

As you can see, "Recovery" shows its identifier `disk5s4` to the right.

2.) Now run the second command with the found identifier, e.g.
`diskutil mount disk5s4`

Knowing your current file system UUID(s) from the first part of this answer, you can now delete the folders in Terminal.

**Example:**

Mount Recovery with `diskutil mount` **and your own found disk identifier**
(`bash-3.2#` is just the command prompt Terminal displays):

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil mount disk5s4
Volume Recovery on disk5s4 mounted
```

Listing of all Volumes mounted under /Volumes with `ls -al /Volumes`:

```
-bash-3.2# ls -al /Volumes
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel   340 Jul 22 14:17 .
drwxrwxr-t  16 root  admin   612 Jul  4 08:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x@ 31 root  wheel   992 Jul 16 22:09 AnotherVolume
drwxr-xr-x@ 30 root  wheel   960 Jul 21 10:59 Installation1
drwxr-xr-x@ 28 root  wheel   896 Jul  6 13:13 Installation2
drwxr-xr-x@ 42 root  wheel  1496 Jul 16 23:27 Macintosh HD
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1 Jul 22 14:15 OS X Base System -> /
drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel   352 Jul 17 13:53 Recovery
```

Changing the directory to /Volumes/Recovery with `cd /Volumes/Recovery` and listing its contents with `ls -al`.  Those are two commands:

```
-bash-3.2# cd /Volumes/Recovery
-bash-3.2# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  11 root      wheel      352 Jul 17 13:53 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 root      wheel      340 Jul 22 14:17 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 _unknown  _unknown  6148 Jul 17 13:54 .DS_Store
d-wx-wx-wt   2 root      wheel       64 Jul 22 14:13 .Trashes
drwx------   5 _unknown  _unknown   160 Feb 24 14:22 .fseventsd
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Feb  8 17:36 05971D12-C9A5-46FB-A70E-2BC0295FAE74
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Jun  4 11:07 23379897-F07E-43A4-A993-03308663CD1B
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Jun 24 10:40 59283231-6D51-412A-B100-D9E205805732
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Jul 21 10:29 AA624F58-E5E8-425C-9698-C1B78C3B0992
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Feb 25 17:06 ADDF591A-10FB-42C4-BDC5-C1C24E6D9217
drwxr-xr-x  11 root      wheel      352 Mar  1 14:19 C9D33FAC-742B-4F16-9DB3-6FFCB5E29DA9
```

Removing the first folder, named `05971D12-C9A5-46FB-A70E-2BC0295FAE74` (as found in the listing above), which I know to be unrelated to the currently in use ones with `rm -r UUID` and answering with "y" (yes) to the question to override:

```
-bash-3.2# rm -r 05971D12-C9A5-46FB-A70E-2BC0295FAE74
override rw-r--r--  root/wheel uchg for 05971D12-C9A5-46FB-A70E-2BC0295FAE74/boot.efi? y
```

Checking that it has been removed:

```
-bash-3.2# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  10 root      wheel      320 Jul 22 14:18 .
drwxr-xr-x   8 root      wheel      340 Jul 22 14:17 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 _unknown  _unknown  6148 Jul 17 13:54 .DS_Store
d-wx-wx-wt   2 root      wheel       64 Jul 22 14:13 .Trashes
drwx------   5 _unknown  _unknown   160 Feb 24 14:22 .fseventsd
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Jun  4 11:07 23379897-F07E-43A4-A993-03308663CD1B
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Jun 24 10:40 59283231-6D51-412A-B100-D9E205805732
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Jul 21 10:29 AA624F58-E5E8-425C-9698-C1B78C3B0992
drwxr-xr-x  13 root      wheel      416 Feb 25 17:06 ADDF591A-10FB-42C4-BDC5-C1C24E6D9217
drwxr-xr-x  11 root      wheel      352 Mar  1 14:19 C9D33FAC-742B-4F16-9DB3-6FFCB5E29DA9
```

The Recovery does not have to be unmounted, as the reboot will unmount it anyway.  Or, if you want to run First Aid in Disk Utility, unmount it with...
   `diskutil umount disk5s4`
 Again using your own disk identifier instead of `disk5s4`

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: im still completely nervous about using terminal commandst. . . have you removed previous UUID folders from volumes you deleted before in the past? im sure that this is how to do it and all, im just wondering if you've done it before

Comment: The two Terminal commands do nothing, but list your disks with a bit more information than Disk Utility and mount the Recovery.  There is nothing to fear here.  If there is anything to be apprehensive about, it's he deletion, but you can do that in Finder, if that makes you feel calmer.  And yes, I've deleted a couple of those folders and the "Recovery" volume did shrink, pass a disk check and did boot afterwards ;)

Comment: Just double check that it's not a currently in use "file system UUID" you are deleting (as described in the answer).  That would prevent booting into the Recovery of that specific volume.

Comment: Unfortunately when i tried to move the other two UUID folders from /Volumes/Recovery it said i dont have permission to access some of the files after I entered my admin password. . . what can i do now? I feel that theres something in the folders that I can delete to reduce the size, but can't delete the folder as a whole.

Additionally i noticed when i mounted the /Volumes/Recovery i didnt see an option or Volume icon to unmount it in the Finder & Disk Utility; restarting my MacBook was able to unmount sucessfully as it said the path was not found

Comment: I was booted into a volume outside the container.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: what am i supposed to type in Terminal to remove the other UUID folders? i know what my current File System UUID is so i wont accidentally delete it, but from youre example im a bit confused on what to type in Terminal to remove the other folders, how to double check it is removed, and how to unmount the /Volumes/Recovery in Recovery Mode. . .(i dont know what "-bash-3.2#" is as im unsure if Terminal types that automatically or if you typed it manually; if manually im unsure if i have to type the same thing or if its different for me)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, i successfully removed the other UUID's that were no longer in use and my 'Other Volumes in Container' storage decreased back down to 1.78 GB. The only thing i found strange was after i was finished with the Terminal commands still in Recovery Mode a first-aid scan on my disk would fail; but i assume thats normal since the recovery volumes were mounted(restarting out and rebooting back into Recovery Mode was able to run a first-aid successfully). Am i correct on that?

Comment: You are correct.   I have - once again - updated my answer :)

Comment: ive been noticing that I see the Recovery disk mounted in /Volumes when I open the path in Finder; usually I eject it or restart my computer but I don't know why its being mounted if its supposed to be hidden. . . any information would be grateful

Comment: @nonope If there are likely more follow-up questions to come, we should start a chat. The Recovery volume gets mounted every time your Mac checks for updates for example (launch Mac App Store > Updates and press cmd+R).  It should get unmounted again shortly after.

Comment: so i noticed a second time that when i restarted my computer and went into /Volumes that the Recovery disk(sometimes a folder) was mounted but didnt get unmounted(volume) when i cmd+R the updates in the App Store. Im unsure how to start up a chat on here so sorry if this is spammy, if you could start one with me directly that be swell but I think I need 2 more rep to be in a chat room :/

Comment: Just sometimes a folder, meaning it disappears by itself?  I have seen a Preboot folder in the past but that was permanent and had to be deleted.  I looked into the chat feature and it looks like you need at least 20 reputation points to post there.

Comment: basically yes; its a folder icon labeled "Recovery" that has a little no access icon at the bottom right corner of it. it disappears after the update check and i assume its the same as the disk volume, correct me if im wrong... also i moved this into a new forum post on the site-(https://bit.ly/2v0Moeg)

Comment: additionally ive noticed that if i have /Volumes stay open in the Finder after a restart i can somewhat see a folder and disk appear very briefly on the screen; the disk if called EFI and the folder was called Firmware(possibly more to it). they appear/disappear very quickly and im not sure what they are, some insight perhaps...

Comment: @nonope It is normal for those three to be mounted at startup.  In Terminal you can have a look at the explanation by typing `man firmwaresyncd` (one of the volumes mounted): "firmwaresyncd runs at boot time to synchronize the firmware file(s) from
     the root filesystem to the EFI System Partition (ESP). It does not run
     when the system is performing a Safe Boot."

Comment: how often does the Recovery volume mount to check up for updates? or what really triggers it to become mounted and check for updates?

Comment: That sounds like a good question to ask the whole forum.

Comment: i think we need to create another private chat as our's was frozen for inactivity